# Array Multiplication using partial product in java

Tags: java, arrays

Here is my work so for.
I want to store the result in a 2d Array and print it in partial products and then sum them all.
I have tried it alot of times as I am a beginner and having a hard time with it.

```
        public class dd {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
            dd obj=new dd();
            System.out.println("Enter 1st Number:");
            String num1=input.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Enter 2nd Number:");
            String num2=input.nextLine();
            dd.convert(num1,num2);
            //dd.multiply();
        }
        public static void convert(String s,String m)
        {
        int[] numbers = new int[s.length()];
        int[] numbers2 = new int[m.length()];
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
        {
           numbers[i] = s.charAt(i) - '0';

        }
         for (int i = 0; i < m.length(); i++)
        {
           numbers2[i] = m.charAt(i) - '0';

        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(numbers));
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(numbers2));
       int [][]result=new int[numbers.length][numbers2.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {

            for (int j = 0; j < result[0].length; j++) {
                result[i][j]=numbers[i]*numbers2[j];
            }
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result));

 }

    }
```

Comment: What error do you get or how is the output. Can you give info about them please?

Comment: I am getting garbage value when storing the product in a 2d array.

Comment: now this is what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Btw you say sum but you multiplie them, is it okey?

Comment: Debug your program step by step and find out, where it does not behave as expected.

Comment: I want to multiply each digit of 1st by another array and then sum the all results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked with java long time ago but it can be a problem about you are trying to cast a char to int array i think. First change it to

```
 for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
 {
       numbers[i] = Character.getNumericValue(s.charAt(i) - '0');

 }
 for (int i = 0; i < m.length(); i++)
 {
       numbers2[i] = Character.getNumericValue(m.charAt(i) - '0');

 }
```

or

```
for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
 {
       numbers[i] = parseInt(s.charAt(i) - '0');

 }
 for (int i = 0; i < m.length(); i++)
 {
       numbers2[i] = parseInt(m.charAt(i) - '0');

 }
```